# Qt 5.15 QML MediaPlayer Segmentation Fault on i.MX6ULL

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtmultimedia

I am trying to embed video in a Qt 5.15 QML (Qt Quick) project running on an i.MX6ULL embedded processor (no GPU), however any inclusion of the Video (or MediaPlayer) components immediately results in the application exiting with a Segmentation Fault.

Even the most basic implementation:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtMultimedia 5.15

Video {
    id: video
    width: 480
    height: 272
    source: "gst-pipeline: videotestsrc ! qtvideosink"
}
```

run with qmlscene immediately exits with a Segmentation Fault.

I am having trouble debugging Qt C++ on the embedded target from Qt Creator (separate issue), however upon the Segmentation Fault there does appear to be a Stack Trace available which includes `QDeclarativeVideoOutput::createBackend(QMediaService*)` (source at https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/src/qtmultimediaquicktools/qdeclarativevideooutput.cpp?h=5.15).

A Qt Widgets application using Qt Multimedia (QMediaPlayer and QVideoWidget) works fine:

```
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
player->setVideoOutput(ui->wgtVid); // wgtVid is a QVideoWidget
player->setMedia(QUrl("gst-pipeline: videotestsrc ! qtvideosink"));
player->play();
```

How can I debug/fix this Segmentation Fault which is occurring with QML (Qt Quick)?

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/143368/qml-mediaplayer-segmentation-fault/8

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-111749